# Decreasing voltage ripple across current sense resistor

Tags: laser-diode

If you ever checked constant current/constant voltage sources such as LT8613 or LT8611, while reading datasheet you probably encoutered such sentence:

> Care
>   must be taken and filters should be used to assure 
>   the signal applied to the ISN and ISP pins has a peak-to-
>   peak ripple of less than 30mV for accurate operation.

It's also said that:

> In 
>   addition to high crest factor current waveforms such as 
>   the input current of DC/DC regulators, another cause of 
>   high ripple voltage across the sense resistor is excessive 
>   resistor ESL. Typically the problem is solved by using a 
>   small ceramic capacitor across the sense resistor or using 
>   a filter network between the ISP and ISN pins.

So, I've tried to simulate such circuit in LTSpice.

I've already put 1uF ceramic capacitor across the sense resistor and added capacitors to feedback (FB) resistors so it wouldn't generate, and it doesn't even on light loads but voltage ripple across current sense resistor is too high so current is set inaccurately. What else would be a good idea?

To put more clarity I add example from typical application. I increased current resistor value to get 100 mA on the output and used diode in series with resistor to simulate load that has 1.3 to 2 V voltage when driven by different current. 
[image: Current source]

Comment: Something else that would be a good idea is add an actual schematic of how you set it up.

Comment: Schematic of typical application added

Comment: A lot of current sense problems are due to incorrect layout. A pic would be useful. Take a look at link below. Figure 1 is right way, Figure 2 wrong way. Figure 2 layout will cause current limit to trigger too early.
http://www.cypress.com/knowledge-base-article/recommended-kelvin-connection-current-sensing-powerpsoc-kba83444

Comment: Also, SMPS needs very strict layout or else you couple the switching noise and inductor ringing all over and you get early triggering of current limit and erratic switching. The input and output cap grounds must be directly connected. App note below is very good.
http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/application-note/an136f.pdf

Comment: What resistor did you use i.e. how much self inductance?

Comment: I can't make it work at simulation level. LTSpice used

Comment: Simulators use ideal characteristics - a real PCB is anything but ideal. Do yourself a favor and treat anything a simulator says with scrutiny.

Comment: Of course, I know that. Nevertheless, getting in to work in program could be a start - if it doesn't work on LTSpice, it isn't going to work in reality, isn't it?

Comment: There are different ways. This is what I would do. With the sense resistor of 0.025, 1A of ripple current (ignoring the 1uF cap) would give 25mV of ripple, which is under the spec. Look at equation (9) in the data sheet of LT8613, which gives the relationship of ripple current \$\Delta I_L\$ and inductor and other parameters. Set \$\Delta I_L\$ to 1A or less and choose the inductance L from that.

Comment: Will try to calculate and share results here as soon as possible!

Answer (score 1):

I resolved an issue according to suggestions **rioraxe** presented. I should always read datasheets more thoroughly. 
 When dealing with buck-mode (step-down) regulators always make sure that current ripple is not exceeded. You can change inductor value and switching frequency quite freely to decrease output voltage or current ripple in exhange of bigger value inductor and energy losses of quick switching.